# C# NUnit Testing for Timer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I am new to unit testing and just started learning it. Here is the code that I am trying to test. This is a wrapper around the System.Threading.Timer that is guarented not to leak exceptions. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<pre>
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MCC.Test.Unit
{

    public class MyTimer : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly TimeSpan NoAutoStartTimer = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);
        private readonly Object _synclock = new object();
        private Timer _internalTimer;

        public MyTimer()
        {
            _internalTimer = new Timer(TimerTick);
        }


        public MyTimer(Action tickHandler) : this()
        {
            Tick += tickHandler;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_internalTimer != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    lock (_synclock)
                    {
                        _internalTimer.Dispose();
                        _internalTimer = null;
                        foreach (Delegate d in Tick.GetInvocationList())
                        {
                            Tick -= (Action) d;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(err);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Called when the timer ticks
        /// </summary>
        public event Action Tick;

        private void TimerTick(Object state)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Tick != null)
                {
                    Tick();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(err);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Schedules the next tick
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="next">The duration until the next sprint</param>
        public void TriggerNextTickIn(TimeSpan next)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (_synclock)
                {
                    if (_internalTimer != null)
                    {
                        _internalTimer.Change(next, NoAutoStartTimer);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
</pre>
```

Comment: What is your question? You may also checkout http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you are just looking for a code review

Comment: The questions is how can I check if the timer ticks, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to test here:

- Testing creation/initialization
- Check if `Tick` comes
- Check if your code does not fail when nobody registered to `Tick`
- Testing `TriggerNextTickIn`

Look at your code as a block box and what it promises and check whether it holds to that promise. Ideally write the tests before you finished the code itself...